# infinite recursion Shiny R

Tags: json, r, for-loop, shiny, infinite-recursion

I am trying to write a for cycle in Shiny. The code should import a json file and combined all the output in one big data.frame. My approach is to initialize a variable with the json output from the first row and then run a loop doing a rbind function to add everything on the bottom so the file can be completed.

The function in a normal R environment works perfectly and it returns what expected.
Here the code:

```
trips<-data.frame(
  time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
  time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
  long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
  long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
  lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
  lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
)

for(i in 2:dim(res.clean)[1]){
trips<-rbind(trips,data.frame(
  time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
  time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
  long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
  long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
  lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
  lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
))}
```

When I try to replicate the approach in Shiny environment i get the error

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Here the code:

```
trips<-reactive({data.frame(
    time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
    time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
    long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
    long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
    lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
    lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
  )})

  trips<-reactive({

    for(i in 1:dim(res.clean())[1]){
    rbind(trips(),data.frame(
      time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
      time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
      long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
      long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
      lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
      lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
    ))}
})

  output$table <- renderTable(trips())
```

The initialization of the trips variable works fine, but when I try to add the cycle it returns the error. Can anyone help please?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Use different names for different reactives. these are functions, they are not executed when they are defined. Therefore after naming the second reactive like the first one, it will call itself, this is why you get that error.

Comment: I thought about that, but if I call the first one, let's say trip1, when it does the rbind function `trips1<-reactive({

    for(i in 1:dim(res.clean())[1]){
    rbind(trips(),data.frame(...` how can merge everything in one file?

Comment: Right. Have a look at `reactiveValues`

Comment: I have tried to read into reactiveValues, but I din't understand how it can apply to my situation. Can you help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
trips<-reactive({
  data <- data.frame(
    time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
    time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
    long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
    long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
    lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
    lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean()[1,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
  )

  for(i in 2:dim(res.clean)[1]){
    data <-rbind(data ,data.frame(
      time.start=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[1:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10))))-1)], 
      time.end=as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))[2:(length(as.numeric((substr((fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$recorded_at),1,10)))))], 
      long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),1],
      long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),1],
      lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))-1),2],
      lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:(length(as.vector(unlist(fromJSON(txt=res.clean[i,2])$loc, recursive = FALSE)))),2]
    ))}

  data 
})
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. If i do `output$table <- renderTable(trips())` the error is `argument of length 0`, if instead i try `
output$table <- renderTable(data())` I have `cannot coerce class ""packageIQR"" to a data.frame`